# Adding a UILabel to a UIImageView

Tags: uiimageview, uilabel

In my app, I am saving an image view with drawings on it. When I try to add the label as a subview to the image view, the image is successfully saved but does not have the label on it. Any thoughts? mainImage is the UIImageView and playNameDisplay is the UILabel.

Here is my code:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mainImage.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.mainImage.frame.size.width, self.mainImage.frame.size.height)];
    [mainImage addSubview:playNameDisplay];
    UIImage *SaveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(SaveImage, self,@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: What version of iOS are you planning on deploying on? Their is a new snapshot api in iOS7 which is super fast for drawing views & their hierarchy into an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using iOS7 you can use the new snapshotting api from apple.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NULL, 0);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rect];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The view you call drawViewHierarchyInRect should be your UIImageView that has your UILabelView as a subview.If you have access to the Apple WWDC 2013 videos you should check out Implementing Engaging UI on iOS. It has some good code examples and also reviews the performance improvement over the more traditional methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with bring subview to front property and check.Like this:

if Label is added as a sub view of image view use this.

```
[self.mainImage bringSubViewToFront:playNameDisplay];
```

if Label and image view is added as a sub view in view:(Nothing but both image view and label over laps) use this.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:playNameDisplay];
```